# get count on specific condition involving multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Here's my sample code. I'm trying to get count of df.result.str.contains('PASS') & df.group.str.contains(fr'\b{name}\b', regex=True)

how to match exact name?

```
# Sample data
data = {
    'group': [
        "/path/to/file/test_abc_n2_manipulation.txt",
        "/path/to/file/test_n2_manipulation.txt",
        "/path/to/file/test_k2_manipulation.txt",
        "/path/to/other/test_abc_a5_manipulation.txt",
        "/path/to/file/some_text.txt",
        "/path/to/file/test_abc_hello.txt"
    ],
    'result': [
        "PASS",
        "PASS",
        "FAIL",
        "FAIL",
        "PASS",
        "PASS"
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
name = "test_abc"
name2 = "test"
results_match = df.result.str.contains('PASS') & df.group.str.contains(fr'\b{name}\b', regex=True)
results_match_2 = df.result.str.contains('PASS') & df.group.str.contains(fr'\b{name2}\b', regex=True)

print(results_match)
print(results_match_2)
```

results_match:
This should give output of 2. But, I'm getting 0 matches.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

results_match_2:
This should give output of 1. But, I'm getting 0 matches.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why your trying to use regular expression along with a formatted string and contains. Its overkill all you need is a formatted string and contains.

```py
results_match = df.result.str.contains('PASS') & df.group.str.contains(f'{name}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I was not clear earlier.. I just updated the question.

Comment: @user3421370 Hey looking at your updated code the same solution I provided would still work. You would just swap the (f'__name__') variable in there to name2

Comment: also @user3421370 on your result_match_2 should give an output of 3 not 1 as your also going to get the result of test and test_abc because both contain the text test.

Answer (score 0):

`_` is not considered a word-boundary as `_` is part of the word characters. Your regex won't match any of the strings:

```
df.group.str.contains(fr'\b{name}\b', regex=True)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: group, dtype: bool
```

You can use `(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])`/`(?:$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])` instead of `\b`:

```
df.group.str.contains(fr'(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9]){name}(?:$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])', regex=True)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: group, dtype: bool
```